# Getting error while buying App windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store

I have uploaded my app to the windows dev store .. now when i try to buy my app its giving error "Service not available . The store isnt available at the moment please try again later. This error code may be helpful 805a01f4".

when i m trying to buy any other app it allow me to buy ..

what should i do to solve this problem ?

[Here's](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/speed-dial-plus/9nblggh1nmj3) the link for app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write to Microsoft tech support.
I've had a problem with downloading my WP7 app some weeks ago. I've write them - they've solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link.
[Windows Dev Center Support](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/community/windows-app-support)

Follow the links and be persistant. Eventually, you'll get some answers. I have been dealing with this same issue for several days and at least I've got a person with Windows Developer Support to answer me, but no solution yet.

Good Luck